# C# Protractor - Finding Element Within Another Element

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, protractor, protractor-net

I am testing an AngularJS app with HTML that looks something like this:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="something in section.questions">
...
</div>
<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="something in section.questions">
...
</div>
<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="something in section.questions">
            <div ng-switch="something.visible">
                <div id="Ins_Othersumarea" class="content-detail-wrap ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-switch-when="true" highlight="something.code == global.highlightedQuestionCode" highlightedcode="global.highlightedQuestionCode" ng-dblclick="logObject(something)">                         
                    <div ng-class="{divider: showDivider(section, $index)}">                                                                                     
                        <div ng-switch="something.type" class="content-detail-section">                                                                 
                            <div class="ng-scope" ng-switch-when="TRIGGER_YES">
                                <ng-include class="ng-scope" src="getFragment('yes-no-fragment.html')" ng-if="!global.interview.isGroup" ng-init="baseQuestion = something">
                             <div class="row ng-scope">
                                 <div class="col-sm-6" ng-switch="baseQuestion.answerValue == undefined &amp;&amp; !global.readonly">
                                     <div class="content-detail-right ng-scope" ng-switch-when="true">
                                         <div class="row">
                                             <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                 <button type="button" id="yes_Ins_Other  sum area" class="btn-base-question-triggers ng-binding" ng-click="answerbaseQuestion(baseQuestion, true)" tabindex="1" setfocus="Ins_Other  sum area">Yes</button>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                 <button type="button" id="no_Ins_Other  sum area" class="btn-base-question-triggers ng-binding" ng-click="answerbaseQuestion(baseQuestion, false)" tabindex="1">No </button>
                                             </div>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
...
```

I am trying to find the nested Yes/No buttons based on the repeater Div text content.

I can find the right ng-repeat element by -

```
var repeatElement = NgDriver.FindElements(NgBy.Repeater("something in section.questions")).First(x => x.Text.Contains("Some Text"));
```

However I cannot figure a way to grab the appropriate Yes/No buttons..

I tried -

```
repeatElement.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'Yes')]"))
```

But that returns the first "Yes" button **on the page** (and not inside the ng-repeat Div like I was expecting).

1. Why??
2. How can I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Are you certain that `repeatElement` is the right element? Have you debug to see the inner HTML of the `repeatElement` yet?

Comment: @Buaban I can see the repeatElement is correct based it's Text property. Regardless I've done as you suggest and it certainly looks correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `repeatElement.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(.,'Yes')]"))`

This is almost correct except that the XPath expression *has to start with a dot* to be context/`repeatElement` specific:

```
repeatElement.FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[contains(.,'Yes')]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yesButton = repeatElement.FindElement(By.Id("yes_Ins_Other"));
```

or

```
var yesButton = repeatElement.FindElements(By.Tag("button")).FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttribute("id") == "yes_Ins_Other");
```